# How to format timestamp in GWT app with given timezone?

Tags: gwt, timezone, format, gmt

I have to format date/time in my gwt app with specific timezone, which is loaded from the server. Possible timezones are like this GMT, GMT+1, GMT-2 etc...
Up to now i used DateTimeFormat to format my timestamps, and they used client's locale.

PLease help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format in any timezone you want with `DateTimeFormat`, you just have to pass it as the second argument to [the `format` method](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date,%20com.google.gwt.i18n.client.TimeZone%29).
And to obtain a `TimeZone` object, depending on how you want to present the timezone information (if ever) in the formatted date/time, you can use either [`createTimeZone(int)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/TimeZone.html#createTimeZone%28int%29) or `createTimeZone(String)` (getting the string out of `TimeZoneConstants`).

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. But the timezone is retrieved from the server in format GMT+/-1,2,3 etc.. So i can't user TimeZoneConstants. I can extract +/-{digit} from the string (for example "GMT+1") and pass it to createTimeZone(int), but i read that this returns different timezone depending in which time zone is the browser (is that true?).

Comment: Er, where did you read that? A timezone offset the distance from UTC, the user's current timezone doesn't matter.

Comment: So, if the loaded server timezone is for example 'GMT-2' i can do the following:
String serverTimeZone = "GMT-2";
int tz = Integer.parseInt(serverTimeZone.substring(3));// returns -2
TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.createTimeZone(tz*60); // this gives me server time zone for GMT-2

//use it to format date/time in GMT-2 time zone